# programación en pascal function (n: integer): integer

Tags: pascal, basic, freepascal

esta función que necesito realizar tiene las siguientes características:

- El parámetro n es un natural menor que 1000.
- La función retorna el valor siguiente a n, según la descripción de la función generadora dada anteriormente.

Necesito implementar una propuesta de función y luego calcular las longitudes de las secuencias que permite producir.

La función propuesta opera con los dígitos del número ordenándolos de manera decreciente y creciente para obtener respectivamente el mayor natural a y el menor natural b que puede formarse con esos dígitos, luego resta ambos números naturales obteniendo a-b.

```
n = d1 d2 ... dh, un número natural,
p1, p2, ..., ph, los dígitos de n ordenados de tal manera que p1 <= ... <= ph,
a = ph ... p2 p1, el mayor natural que se puede formar con los dígitos de n, 
b = p1 p2 ... ph, el menor natural que se puede formar con los dígitos de n,
```

entonces:

```
f(n) = a - b
```

Por ejemplo, si `n = 043`, entonces `a = 430`, `b = 034` y `f(n) = 396`.

Esta trabaja con números de 3 dígitos (naturales menores a 1000) y solo se va a comprobar si se generan dos números iguales consecutivos.

Un ejemplo es `063` es `063`, `594`, `495`, ya que luego se repetiría el 495, como se ve en la siguiente tabla.

```
----------
n   a   b   a-b
----------
063 630 036 594
----------
594 954 459 495
----------
495 954 459 495
----------
```

Con naturales de menos de tres dígitos, agregamos ceros a la izquierda.

Los números pueden tener dígitos repetidos. Un ejemplo lo vemos en la siguiente tabla que genera la secuencia `111, 000`

```
----------
n   a   b   a-b
----------
111 111 111 000
----------
000 000 000 000
----------
```

Comencé a realizar la programación y quería saber que recomendaciones me dan para que me lean los números iniciales y continuar:

```
program;

begin

  type
     n: 00..1000

  function x (n: integer): integer

  var n: integer;

  begin


  end;

end.
```

Comment: Seguramente con arreglos y subarreglos que no me estoy dando cuenta ahora.

Comment: Como le dije a ¿tu compañera? en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/395938/21), esta es una tarea que tu debes realizar. En su forma actual, la pregunta es una solicitud para que alguien haga tu trabajo. Vamos, que tu incluyes algo de código, solo pares `begin/end`. Si demuestras algún esfuerzo, seguramente encontrarás la ayuda que buscas por aquí.